# Timeit module for qgis plugin

Tags: python, qgis

I'd like to use the python module **`timeit`** to time some functions in my QGIS plugin.

Here, I've called the time it function within a function that I call at the end of the last function. It seems, though, that the plugin is taking even longer to run than usual and I am wondering if i'm calling the timer in the wrong place. Is there a better way to set this up?

```
class myPluginName:

    def firstFunction(self):
        ...
        self.secondFunction()

    def secondFunction(self):
        ...
        self.timeThings()

    def run(self):
        self.firstFunction()

    def timeThings(self):
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'First Function', 'Time : %s' % timeit.timeit(self.firstFunction,number=1)
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'Second Function', 'Time : %s' % timeit.timeit(self.secondFunction,number=1)
```

UPDATE: After following some advice, i've tried to implement the wrapper in the following way. I get however, a `TypeError: firstFunction() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) on ret = func(**args, **kwargs)`

```
def time_func(func):
    try:
        name = func.__name__
    except:
        name = func.f__name
    def tf_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        QMessageLog.logMessage("{}: {}".format(name, time.time() - t))
        return ret
    return tf_wrapper

class myPlugin:
    def initGui(self):
        QObject.connect(self.dlg.ui.comboBox,SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self.firstFunction)
    @time_func
    def firstFunc(self):
        registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
        firstID = str(self.dlg.ui.firstCombo.itemData(self.dlg.ui.firstCombo.currentIndex()))
        secondID = str(self.dlg.ui.secondCombo.itemData(self.dlg.ui.secondCombo.currentIndex()))
        self.firstLayer = registry.mapLayer(firstID)
        self.secondLayer = registry.mapLayer(secondID)

    @time_func
    def secondFunc(self):
        ...
        self.thirdFunc()
    def thirdFunct(self):
        ...
    def run(self):
        self.dlg.ui.firstCombo.clear()
        self.dlg.ui.secondCombo.clear()
        for layer in self.iface.legendInterface().layers():
            if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                self.dlg.ui.firstCombo.addItem(layer.name(), layer.id())
                self.dlg.ui.secondCombo.addItem(layer.name(), layer.id())
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        if result == 1:
            self.secondFunction()
```

Comment: @matsjoyce I call multiple functions in a few different ways. The first is called with a change in combo box index. The second is with an accept button on a dialog box. I also have functions called from within functions. See edits.

Comment: @matsjoyce i just added more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know your exact situation, but I'd set it up though decorators:

```
import time

def time_func(func):
    try:
        name = func.__name__
    except:
        name = func.f_name
    def tf_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("{}: {}".format(name, time.time() - t))  # Or use QMessageBox
        return ret
    return tf_wrapper

class myPluginName:
    @time_func
    def firstFunction(self):
        pass

    @time_func
    def secondFunction(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.firstFunction()
myPluginName().firstFunction()
```

With this code, any function wrapped in `time_func` will have the time taken to execute the function printed when it returns, along with its name. E.g. running it will print:

```
firstFunction: 1.430511474609375e-06
```

For your `TypeError`, you need to change;

```
    def firstFunction(self):
        pass
```

To:

```
    def firstFunction(self, index):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the cause of my error. I'm wondering, though, if this is the setup. Is it better if the timit function are called during the functions itself? I'm going to update my question a bit now that i've bypassed by initial error.

Comment: this looks like just what i'm looking for, but it's a bit new to me. I get a TypeError: myFunction() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) on the line ret = func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @user25976 That's wierd... How did you call it?